# How to write assertion for dynamically change dropdown value in Jmeter

Tags: jmeter

I have prepared my script using Correlation-regular expression. How can I provide the assertion for account which is selected from .csv file. Here the account selection is stored in a regular expression as follows.
[CSV_Data_set_Config](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YuHNn.png), [CSV_File_info](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AzWtS.png), [Account_Selection_From_UI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a5MDy.png),  [Regular_Expression](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YyUOy.png), [Sample_Thread_Group](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1RwFQ.png), [Response_Assertion](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GSJ2M.png)

Answer (score 0):

Your screenshots are very beautiful but you need to specify what do you want to compare with what in order to get a comprehensive answer.

If you need to compare this `0048852` with the value from the CSV file you need to:

1. Extract this `0048852` using [Regular Expression Extractor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Regular_Expression_Extractor) or [Boundary Extractor](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/the-boundary-extractor-vs-the-regular-expression-extractor-in-jmeter)
2. Add [Response Assertion](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Response_Assertion) as a child of the request and configure it like:

   [image]

For more detailed response you need to share at least partial HTML code of the page where the dropdown is selected showing the [dropdown markup](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_select.asp) and indicate what exact value you need to "assert"

Comment: Thank you Dmitri, I tried this way and it's worked for me, but my code is failing during enter reference number submittion. It has to fail at account selection level only. Attached the "sample thread group" and the Assertion which I have used for the account in above Question itself. Please suggest me how to add this. What ever the account selected from csv should match with UI.

Comment: It looks like you're comparing the variable with itself so I doubt that the assertion really works. If it does for some reason and it's failing the sampler it shouldn't fail - move it ot be a child of the sampler which you want to assert. See [JMeter Scoping Rules - The Ultimate Guide](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-scoping-rules-the-ultimate-guide) article for more details